# JavaFX RadioButton Event Handling

Tags: event-handling, radio-button, javafx-2

What kind of JavaFX2 event is fired when selecting a radio button from a group and how can I handle it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given `zodiacSigns` is a group which radio buttons belong to,

```
zodiacSigns.selectedToggleProperty().addListener(new OnToggleHandler());
```

will the event handler `OnToggleHandler` to the button group (called toggle group in JavaFX). Below is the code for `OnToggleHandler`

```
private class OnToggleHandler implements ChangeListener<Toggle> {

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Toggle> ov, Toggle t, Toggle t1) {
        dailyHoro.editReading(((RadioButton) t1).getText());
        dailyHoro.print();
        System.out.println("Old: " + ((RadioButton) t).getText() + ", New: " + ((RadioButton) t1).getText());
        if (dailyHoro.getText() == null)
            textEditor.setText("");
        else
            textEditor.setText(dailyHoro.getText());
    }
}
```